# SQL Trigger On Different Tables

Tags: sql, foreach, triggers

I have a Database that looks like this.

[image: Current database]

Whenever a new user is created, the Id of the User(*UserName*) needs to be stored in the **Budget** table. After this, I want the attribute *category* in the **Budget** table to be filled with every category in the **Category** table.

My current **Category** table:

[image: The data in the Category table]

As you can see, I currently have 3 categories. Is it possible to create a Trigger which loops trough the categories, and inserts the *Category.Id* into *Budget.Category*.

The Budget table should look like this after a user has been created:

[image: Budget table after a user has been created]

I don't know how to add each categoryId to the Budget table.

Comment: Yes, you can do this.  Start with a `create trigger on insert` statement.

Comment: I'm stuck on the part where I have to loop trough the Categories and add each one to the Budget table.

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Then you should edit your question and show the work you have done.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

To insert the values into the `budget` table, the code would look something like this:

```
insert into budget(UserId, CategoryId, Date, Value)
    select new.userid, c.categoryId, current date, 0
    from categories c;
```

No `foreach` is required, but the syntax varies by database.  In particular:

- The syntax for the current date.
- The syntax for accessing the values being inserted.